# How to generate models from database structure existing

Tags: database, postgresql, django-models, entity-relationship, case-tools

There is some tool or application that take a backup/export (.sql file may be) of a database and can generate like result the entity-relation model, this mean, the tables in a graphic?

My database is in PostgreSQL, although this will should transparent?

Another question. In django, is possible generate the model entity relation from models in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any working from the sql dump but from running postrgresql db **schemaSpy** works very well and easly

```
java -jar schemaSpy.jar -t dbType -db dbName [-s schema] -u user [-p password] -o outputDir
```

here an example of [output](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html)